# UITextfield in a custom uicollectioncell - delegate methods not being called

Tags: delegates, uitextfield, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple uicollectionviewcell with some buttons and a uitextfield. Tapping the uitextfield pops the keyboard but my Done button makes the keyboard 'blink' and then the uppercase arrows fill in. Weird.

None of my uitextfield methods are called (I have them logged). The uitextfield is in the nib file and I tried setting delegate in code and in IB. Neither work but doing it in IB causes a crash with no info other than ldb.

I also have the Return key set to Done.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was dragging the delegate to the files owner - it needed to be dragged to the cells view. Solved.